# Why does a software bibliography entry not print that it's software?

Tags: biblatex

I would like to cite a piece of software that is published on a website (a git repository). The `@software` entry seems most applicable but the `@misc` entry has a `type` field for software. A minimal example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@Misc{Foo2019,
  author   = {Authors},
  title    = {Foo},
  type     = {software},
  url      = {https://example.com},
  urldate  = {2019-12-12},
  year     = {2019},
}

@Software{Foo2019b,
  author   = {Authors},
  title    = {Foo},
  url      = {https://example.com},
  urldate  = {2019-12-12},
  year     = {2019},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{test.bib}
\begin{document}
My cite~\cite{Foo2019,Foo2019b}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

However, only the `@misc` is printed as

> [Aut19] Authors.Foo.Comp.software.2019.

using the `alphabetic` style. Whereas the "Comp. software" is left out for the `@software` entry. Why is that?

Comment: Usually `biblatex` will print the `url` field for all entry types. Did you specifically tell `biblatex` not to print URLs with `url=false`? Can you please show us a complete example document (with `\documentclass` `\begin{document}...\end{document}`) that shows how exactly you call `biblatex`, a so-called MWE (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) or MWEB (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864).

Comment: There is a specific entry type for software citations: `@software`. You may want to use that instead of the generic `@misc`. This will quite probably not resolve the immediate issue here, since in the standard styles `@software` is treated as an alias for `@misc` so that the output should be virtually identical, but it is still a good idea to make use of the available entry types.

Comment: @moewe, thanks, I somehow had missed that when I was checking my configuration options.  Now it works.
In response to using `@software`, that actually loses the "Comp. software" in the output so it is less specific. I think it may be aliased to `@misc` without the type field.

Comment: I just checked and for me `@software` does not lose the "Comp. software" (and indeed that would surprise me since `@software` is really just an alias of `@misc` and there is no attempt to remove any fields here). Are you using the current version of `biblatex` (v3.14)? Can you provide an MWE for that issue?

Comment: I've added an MWE which illustrates the issue but I am on 3.13a so I'm updating now to see if it makes a difference. Note that for the `@software` entry I remove the type field myself since it doesn't make sense to put a `type={software}` in a software entry. Maybe that's it?

Comment: Updated and issue also exists on 3.14

Comment: A meta question: Should I see if I can rephrase the question to pertain the `@software` instead? The `url=false` issue is kind of moot so perhaps this would be more informative.

Comment: I think that would make sense in this circumstance, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can not reproduce the issue with the URL as the standard styles print the URL unless explicitly instructed to do otherwise (with `url=false,`).

The result of the MWE is expected if we keep in mind that `@software` is treated exactly like `@misc` by the standard styles. So if there is no `type` field, `@software` does not show a type.

It is not hard to add that type field automatically with a sourcemap, though.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex, overwrite=false]{
    \map{
      \step[typesource=software, final]
      \step[fieldset=type, fieldvalue={software}]
    }
  }
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{Foo2019a,
  author   = {Authors},
  title    = {Foo},
  type     = {software},
  url      = {https://example.com},
  urldate  = {2019-12-12},
  year     = {2019},
}
@software{Foo2019b,
  author   = {Authors},
  title    = {Foo},
  url      = {https://example.com},
  urldate  = {2019-12-12},
  year     = {2019},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
My cite~\autocite{Foo2019a,Foo2019b}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Authors. Foo. Comp. software. 2019. url: https://example.com (visited on 12/12/2019).//Authors. Foo. Comp. software. 2019. url: https://example.com (visited on 12/12/2019).]

If you think that the `type` field of a `@software` entry should automatically be populated with `software`, you can open an issue at https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues to discuss this.