# Citing software using revtex

Tags: citing, revtex

I am trying to cite a Zenodo project using revtex4.2. In my .bib file, I use an entry which is obtained using Zenodo's bibtex export feature. However, when I cite this using revtex4.2, I get

> [xx] John Doe, jdoe/code-for-paper: Initial release. (1954).

So revtex4.2 seems to leave out all the relevant information of the `software` publication type and only gives author+title+year.

Is there a fix for this? Am I doing something wrong?

Additional info: I am using the `longbibliography` argument of revtex.

EDIT: For github and pypi software entries according to recommended formatting the output is even worse (see modified example), with no useful information whatsoever.

---

Minimum working example:

main.tex:

```
\documentclass[%
aps,
pra,
amsmath,amssymb,showpacs,
reprint,
floatfix,
twocolumn,
nofootinbib,
longbibliography,
superscriptaddress
]{revtex4-2}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    
    \title{The title}
    
    
    \author{The author}
    
    \begin{abstract}
        This paper is based on \cite{zenodo1,github1,pypi1}.
    \end{abstract}
    
    \maketitle
    
    % bibliography
    \bibliography{library}
    
\end{document}
```

library.bib:

```
@software{zenodo1,
    author       = {John Doe},
    title        = {jdoe/code-for-paper: Initial release.},
    month        = jan,
    year         = 1954,
    publisher    = {Zenodo},
    version      = {v0.0.0},
    doi          = {00.0000/zenodo.0000000},
    url          = {https://doi.org/00.0000/zenodo.0000000}
}
@software{github1,
    author       = {John Doe},
    title        = {project},
    url          = {https://github.com/jdoe/project}
}
@software{pypi1,
    author       = {John Doe},
    title        = {project},
    url          = {https://pypi.org/project/project/}
}
```

Output:
[image]

Note that in my real example, I also use a rather long style file myprsty.bst (commented out above). It does not appear to affect the output of the software entry.

Comment: Can you please add a minimal example?

Comment: @egreg Apologies, I should have done that from the start. I've added a minimal example now.

Comment: Just for general awareness, the result is much better in the article class with `@software` than with `@misc`, cf. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/536040/34551 revtex4.2 _should_ do something similar.

Comment: @Clément that's `biblatex`, not `article` doing the heavy lifting.  `@software` is a non-standard `bibtex` entry type, `revtex` (or more precisely the default bst, `apsrev`) is doing nothing unusual by not supporting it.

Comment: @Wolpertinger `apsrev` (the default `revtex` bst) doesn't support `@software` like most standard bibtex styles so is falling back on `@misc` which ignores keys like version.  If you want them to appear then put them into the title or note, but for `github1` and `pypi1` it's printing everything you give it (as well as brackets for the year which you haven't supplied) and adding the hyperlink: what do you actually want to happen to those?